# Visual Studio Not Finding Latest NuGet Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

About 8 hours ago, I published a new prelease to NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XrmUnitTest.2015/1.1.4-alpha05
And now I'm trying to reference it from Visual Studio, but it's not finding the 1.1.4-Alpha05 release, only the 1.1.4-Alpha03.

[image]

[image]

Even attempting to update manually doesn't work:

```
PM> Install-Package XrmUnitTest.2015 -Version 1.1.4-alpha05 -Pre
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'XrmUnitTest.2015.1.1.4-alpha05' with respect to project 'Defender.Xrm', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Install-Package : Package 'XrmUnitTest.2015' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Please verify all your online package sources 
are available.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package XrmUnitTest.2015 -Version 1.1.4-alpha05 -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Seems the "Catalog2Registration" job is down right now.  It is Sunday, give them at least 24 hours to fix it.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a status page somewhere for that?

Comment: I saw that in the issue tracker.  From a bug report filed by somebody because he saw the status page not showing the job being down :)  Not for public consumption I'd assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like NuGet is having an issue.

[image]

If this ever happens again in the future, refer to http://status.nuget.org/